# Perl not returning PID

Tags: linux, perl, bash, pid

If I run the command

```
nohup ./run > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

in my terminal I get back something along the lines of `[1] 1234` which I understand to be the PID.

However, when I run the following in Perl, it returns an error about `disown` not being defined or something, but that's not the point. When I remove `disown`, the terminal returns the same thing but Perl returns nothing. The variable it was assigned to is just blank.

```
my $command = `nohup ./run > /dev/null 2>&1 &`;
print("a " . $command); // "a " to check if it's actually printing anything.
```

Output:

```
a
```

Expected output:

```
[1] 1234
```

How do I get Perl to display the PID of the command which I can then parse with

```
@ar  = split(/\s+/, $process);
$pid = $ar[1];
```

Which was provided by another Stackoverflow user in my previous question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[1] 1234` is only output by bash for interactive shells (i.e. one started with the `-i` option).

```
my $command = `sh -ic 'nohup ./run > /dev/null 2>&1 &' 2>&1`;
die "Can't execute child: $!\n"                if $? < 0;
die "Child killed by signal ".($? & 0x7F)."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
die "Child exited with error ".($? >> 8)."\n"  if $? >> 8;
```

or better yet,

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capture );
capture(q{sh -ic 'nohup ./run > /dev/null 2>&1 &' 2>&1});
```

Another option is to "daemonize" using [Daemon::Daemonize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Daemon::Daemonize). Unfortunately, it only returns the PID via a pid file.

Comment: ug, I forgot to actually use the option that made this work. Fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, both still return null

Comment: There's no such thing as null. Elaborate.

Comment: It returns an empty string, then. If I use `print` it prints nothing.

Comment: If you have problems making your shell output `[1] 1234`, you should start by mentioning what shell you're using. (`sh --version`?) You should also tag your question for that shell as your question has nothing to do with Perl.

Comment: I'm using bash. My shell outputs it, but the above script doesn't. `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release`

Comment: You sure you used `-i`? What do you get from executing `sh -ic 'nohup ./run > /dev/null 2>&1 &'` from the prompt? (My `sh` is bash 4.1.5)

Comment: I got it working, I had to change `sh` to `bash`. Only problem I have now is that both the examples get printed out directly and not captured.

Comment: @Jordan Doyle, Fixed.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for baring with me throughout this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $pin1=`(nohup ./run >/dev/null 2>&1 \& echo \$! )`
```

Comment: Can you explain that this does?

Comment: my answser is similar to @ikegami : my $command = `sh -ic 'nohup ./run > /dev/null 2>&1 &' 2>&1`;
 except my code gets the pin from bash shell "echo $!".